# Why do I need to save Configurable Products 2x times?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, api, save

I am having problems on **putting my product in stock**.
I create it, I associate simple products to it, and it works fine.
**Visibility and simple products stock** are also correct.

The **big problem here** is that when I refresh the homepage it just won't show up.

Then i found an issue:

- When i go to Magento Admin Page -> Catalog -> Manage Products , and click on the configurable product, It looks like it is well configurated.

**Associated products page:**

[image]

**Inventory page:**

[image]

What happens next: When I **save** again (this time manually, not programmatically) it just works without any problems. I also noticed that when i give categories to the product It won't associate it on FrontEnd but it will link in BackEnd only. The fix for this one is the same as the first problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your Magento needs re-indexing.

After making your changes, go to System > Index Management > Reindex Data and it should update the front-end.

More about Magento Index Management:
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/index-management.html?Highlight=indexing

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)